# How to call a method in Linq query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Of course I made some research and tried something but can't make it.

I have this code so far:

```
var workLogs = (from wl in _db.WorkLogs
                        where (wl.Users_UserId == userId && wl.Works_WorkId == workId && wl.Date > beginDate && wl.Date < endDate)
                        select new
                        {
                            wl.Users_UserId,
                            wl.Works_WorkId,
                            wl.Time,
                            wl.Date
                        })
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(wl => new 
                       { 
                           userName = GetUserNameFromId(wl.Users_UserId), 
                           workName = GetWorkNameFromId(wl.Works_WorkId),
                           wl.Time,
                           wl.Date
                       });
```

As you can see I tried enumeration but when I run the application, workLogs comes empty. And when I inspect it with a breakpoint, I see "Enumeration yielded no results."

What I trying to make is return work and user name in workLogs. And I wrote two method to do this. I just cant call them in my Linq query.

Without my methods, it works good as you can see it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCdVx.png

And my methods also works good outside of query.

I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: So, get rid of the two methods and see what happens. Besides, what kind of "LINQ" is it? LINQ to SharePoint?

Comment: try using a non-deferred operation such as `ToArray` first.

Comment: @John Saunders -  
No it's Entities. How I can get work names or user names based on their id's if i get rid of that two methods? I am working on MVC and I don't want to write Linq queries in my views.

Comment: @Wren I don't see why you are returning the first `anonymous type` or the `AsEnumerable()` call.

Comment: Yeah, the `select`, `AsEnumerable` and `Select` won't be causing you to have no results; it's only the `where` than can be doing this.

Comment: Firstly, My code wasn't have AsEnumerable and following part of it. And it was working without my custom methods. And I wrote my custom methods to return names instead of id's in my first "select new" part. So Linq couldn't identify my methods in there. Then I made some research and added AsEnumerable and others. But now it says "Enumeration yielded no results."

Comment: Okay. I will check whole code and will write another comment. Thanks.

Comment: I would remove the two methods as a diagnostic tool. See if you get any data with the two methods removed.

Comment: @John Saunders - http://i.imgur.com/ALb5f0K.png As you can see it works good without my methods. You can see user and work id's in workLogs.

And i must note that also my methods work good outside of query.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no results then it means your underlying source doesn't have data, or your `where` clause is filtering out more than you think it should be.  There is no problem that you could have with your `select` statement(s) that would cause a sequence that would normally return results to instead return no results.  At most you could cause it to throw an exception.

Comment: Okay. I will check whole code and will write another comment. Thanks.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ALb5f0K.png As you can see it works good without my methods. You can see user and work id's in workLogs.

And i must note that also my methods work good outside of query.

Comment: @Wren Then either you are getting an exception thrown, or you're not properly observing the functionality using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why the following code should not work. You do not need other code to make this work.
If this return no results, it just means that the where clause is filtering everything.
Make a manual foreach with a if statement to debug this and you will see that there is no problem with your LINQ request.

```
var workLogs = from wl in _db.WorkLogs
                        where (wl.Users_UserId == userId && wl.Works_WorkId == workId && wl.Date > beginDate && wl.Date < endDate)
                        select new
                        {
                            GetUserNameFromId(wl.Users_UserId),
                            GetWorkNameFromId(wl.Works_WorkId),
                            wl.Time,
                            wl.Date
                        }
```

Comment: It shows red underline on my methods. And says;

Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: I am sorry, you should of course keep the "userName =" & "workName =" part before GetXXX function. Otherwise the compiler does not know which name to give to your anonymous type members.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `.AsEnumerable()` with `.ToArray()`.